# Calculate yearly cumulative sales in neighbourhoods, up to three years after the first sale

Tags: r, date, time

For this problem I need to calculate the quarterly cumulative sales per neighbourhood. The tricky part is that I only have a table where every row corresponds to one unique person, and a column containing the 'Sale' and 'Date of sale', so years need to be created, as some years there can be no sales.

Another requirement is that only sales that fall within three years after the first sale in that neighbourhood are to be considered. My dataframe looks like this:

```r
dat <- tibble(
  Person = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  Neighbourhood = c("XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC"),
  Date_of_sale =  structure(c(17987, NA, 19275, 17564, 18052, NA), class = "Date"),
  Sale = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
)
dat
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Person Neighbourhood Date_of_sale  Sale
#>    <dbl> <chr>         <date>       <dbl>
#> 1      1 XYZ           2019-04-01       1
#> 2      2 XYZ           NA               0
#> 3      3 XYZ           2022-10-10       1
#> 4      4 XYZ           2018-02-02       1
#> 5      5 ABC           2019-06-05       1
#> 6      6 ABC           NA               0
```

The desired output looks like this:

| Neighbourhood | Year | Cumulative Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | Year 1 | 1 |
| XYZ | Year 2 | 2 |
| XYZ | Year 3 | 2 |
| ABC | Year 1 | 1 |
| ABC | Year 2 | 1 |
| ABC | Year 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being exact about leap years in this kind of problem is somewhat of a pain in R. Thus, I am approximating the year length with `365.25` days. Look to the comments for explanations of the steps.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat <- tibble(Person = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),  Neighbourhood = c("XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC"),  Date_of_sale =  structure(c(17987, NA, 19275, 17564, 18052, NA), class = "Date"),  Sale = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))

sol <- dat |> 
  filter(Sale == 1) |> # keep only persons with sales
  arrange(Neighbourhood, Date_of_sale) |>
  group_by(Neighbourhood) |> 
  mutate(year = ((Date_of_sale - min(Date_of_sale) + 1)/365.25) |> # bring time diff to year level
          unclass() |> 
          ceiling() # round up to full year
         ) |> 
  group_by(Neighbourhood, year) |> 
  summarize(sales = sum(Sale)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  complete(Neighbourhood, year = 1:3, fill = list(sales = 0)) |> # Add year without sales
  filter(year <= 3) |> # Remove years greater than 3
  group_by(Neighbourhood) |> 
  mutate(cum_sales = cumsum(sales)) |>  # Cumulate sales across years
  ungroup()

sol
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Neighbourhood  year sales cum_sales
#>   <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 ABC               1     1         1
#> 2 ABC               2     0         1
#> 3 ABC               3     0         1
#> 4 XYZ               1     1         1
#> 5 XYZ               2     1         2
#> 6 XYZ               3     0         2
```